# Instantiating anonymous class during page load

Tags: javascript

I have encountered the following odd behaviour:

During load:

```
var a = new function() {};
alert(typeof a);          //outputs function instead of object
```

Executing the exact same code AFTER the page has loaded yields object instead of function, as expected.

The following does return object but I would like to avoid it if possible:

```
function b(){}
var a = new b();
alert(typeof a);         //outputs object
```

Am I missing something here? Why doesn't the first example give me an object reference instead of a function?

Tested on:

Firefox 24

Chrome 28

IE 10

**EDIT:**

It turns out that it isn't a browser problem but a bug with Brackets' Live Preview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var a = new function() {};
            alert(typeof a); //should output 'object' but outputs 'function' in Brackets
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `new function` is not the same as calling a constructor with `new`.

Comment: @elclanrs How come I get different results when the code is executed during load compared to after load?

Comment: What do you mean by "after load", can you post a fiddle?

Comment: So, you're running this in 'Brackets Live Preview'? What is that? You should probably include which browser you're using in future questions

Comment: Work with Google Chrome 30 and Firefox 23

Answer (score 0):

well, when you call

```
var a = function () {}
```

you are declaring a function

but instead with

```
function b(){}
var a = new b();
alert(typeof a);
```

you`re instansiating the B function, which works as an object, thats why returns object, regards.

thats when you use the new keyword.